# AndEngine how to make entity to move in circle?

Tags: entity, andengine

i just want to make an entity to move in circle, is there any way to achieve this without using physicBox Extention? Perhaps some entity modifier?

thanks for responds, i work in AndEngine anchorCenter.

Comment: see my answer at http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/moving-sprite-around-a-fixed-point-t4063.html#p49789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving sprite around a fixed point

http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles1/moving-sprite-around-a-fixed-point-t4063.html#p49789

you can implement like this.

```
package com.circular.demo;

import org.andengine.engine.camera.Camera;
import org.andengine.engine.handler.IUpdateHandler;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.FillResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.primitive.Rectangle;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.background.Background;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;
import org.andengine.util.color.Color;

import android.view.WindowManager;

public class Main extends SimpleBaseGameActivity{

public static final int CAMERA_WIDTH    = 800;
public static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT   = 480;

Camera _camera;

double _radius = 150;
double _angle = 0;

double _center_point_x = 400;//(CAMERA_WIDTH/2)
double _center_point_y = 240;//(CAMERA_HEIGHT/2)

float _speed = 1;

Rectangle _r;
Rectangle _g;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    this._camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    final EngineOptions _eo = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
            new FillResolutionPolicy(), _camera);

    return _eo;
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scene _s = new Scene();

    _s.setBackground(new Background(Color.BLUE));

    _g = new Rectangle((float)_center_point_x, (float)_center_point_y, 15f, 15f, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    _g.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    _r = new Rectangle((float)_center_point_x, (float)_center_point_y, 10f, 10f, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    _r.setColor(Color.RED);

    _s.attachChild(_g);
    _s.attachChild(_r);

    _s.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

        @Override
        public void reset() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            _angle+=pSecondsElapsed * _speed;

            final double _x = _radius * Math.cos(_angle) + _center_point_x;
            final double _y = _radius * Math.sin(_angle) + _center_point_y;

            _g.setPosition((float)_x, (float)_y);
        }
    });

    return _s;
}



}
```

may help you..

Answer (score -1):

You may want like

> [Circle Rush](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=webndroid.circlerush).

Right?

Comment: I moved sprite just the way you want.

Comment: You may contact me on jagruttam@gmail.com